Running cmd or PowerShell script with OpenTelemetry Collector Contrib - config yaml to bring SQL Server version
I am trying to execute/run cmd or powershell script (ps1 file) with the OpenTelemetry Collector Contrib - config yaml file.
Following powershell script brings the installed SQL Server version at Windows PCs.
Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Product WHERE Name LIKE 'Microsoft SQL Server%'" | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*Setup*" } | Sort-Object InstallDate -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 -Property Name, Version, InstallDate
Powershell script output
How can I execute/run this script (ps1 file) with config.yaml?
I know there is a different way by using sqlqueryreceiver and using "SELECT @@VERSION" query, I tried and it works but this needs sql connection (with password), and I don't want to write the credentials in config file, so I am trying to find more secure/efficient way to bring the installed SQL Server version with ps script to run with config.yaml.
